# Call to a member function fetch_object() on resource

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop

I have written this PHP file which contains SQL to gather all posts in a table.

```
$selectpost = mysql_query("
SELECT 
posts.id,
COUNT(post_likes.id) AS likes

FROM posts

LEFT JOIN post_likes
ON posts.id = post_likes.post

GROUP BY posts.id

");

while($row = $selectpost->fetch_object()) {

$posts[] = $row;    
}
```

for some reason i keep getting this error:

Call to a member function fetch_object() on resource in posts.php on line 23

line 23 is the while loop:

```
while($row = $selectpost->fetch_object()) {
```

connecting to database like this:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'account', 'password');

$dbs = mysql_select_db('site');
```

what is wrong, i cant fix it..

Comment: You're mixing APIs that don't intermix with each other. Use "one" and only one. Had it been *gin & tonic*, fine. But not for this.

Comment: So then how can I fix the while loop?

Comment: I don't know. I need to firstly know, which API you're using to connect to your db with. That's the root of database work.

Comment: i have editted the question to show you.

Comment: `mysql_` + `mysql_` = success `mysqli_` +  `mysqli_` = success. PDO with PDO = success. Drop a wrench in one of those and it will fail. I.e.:  `mysqli_` + `mysql_` or PDO = fail.

Comment: so dont use fetch_object?

Comment: **A:** Don't use any functions that are not `mysql_` based.

Comment: so can I use $dbs->query("etc

Comment: Nope. That's an object oriented method which `mysql_` does not have the capability of. `mysqli_` does.

Answer (score 0):

$selectpost->fetch_object() is a mysqli fucntion so $selectpost needs to be a mysqli result.

for mysql_query() uses the non object oriented mysql_fetch_object( )

basically you mysql_query() hasn't returned a mysqli object but your trying to make mysqli methos calls on it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mysql_ PHP extension so you would have to use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($selectpost)) {
```

Of course you should really not be using the mysql_ extension as it is deprecated

Comment: what do I use instead?

Comment: Either the PDO extension or the MYSQLI_ extension the choise is yours. I still cannot decide which is better. _Bet that gets a comment or 1000_

Comment: *"If I use mysqli_ though i get a ton of errors –  fire_head"* - Again, [this is the reason...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946551/call-to-a-member-function-fetch-object-on-resource#comment46147306_28946551) @fire_head - *Plus*, `mysqli_` requires DB connection be passed to their functions.